# Orthogonality of vectors still maintain？

Tags: matrices, vectors, orthogonality

Suppose theres is an orthogonal vector set $\{x_1, x_2,...,x_k\}$, in which $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, and $n\gg k\gg m$. If the vector $Ax_1$ is orthogonal to vector set $\{Ax_2,...,Ax_k\}$，which means for $\forall j \in \{2,...,k\}$, the inner product $(Ax_1, Ax_j)$ is zero. Then, what conditions should matrix $A$ satisfy?

Is the information enough for we to make some restrictions on $A$? Any discussion about $A$ may be helpful. Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I you want to get $\gg$, I suggest that you use `\gg`.